# how to set caption under an image inside an mdframed environment with \InsertBoxR

Tags: captions, mdframed

I was trying to set a caption on an image that was placed within an mdframed box at the right side of the document. the structure is like

```
\begin{mdframed}[frametitle={my title},style = MyFrame] \label{box: storysn1}
\input{insbox}
\lipsum[1]
\InsertBoxR{2}{\enspace\includegraphics[width=0.39\textwidth]{images/annales.PNG}}
\lipsum[2]
\end{mdframed}
```

i tried using \caption inside \insertBoxR but it raise errors.
does anyone know how to correctly set the caption in cases like this one?  thanks

example of what i want to achieve ( ijust want a caption under the image)
[image]

what i get with /parbox

```
\parbox{5cm}{ \raggedleft \includegraphics[width = 5cm]{images/annales.PNG}}
```

[image]

Comment: I would put the \includegraphicx in a `\parbox` and use `\captionof{figure}{Some caption}` after a blank line (requires the `caption` package).

Comment: @Bernard hi bernard, i tried using '\parbox' as you said but the text goes over the image. is there something else i need to set? i have not used latex for a long time

Comment: Did you set the width of the \parbox?

Comment: @bernard ah yes,now the text doesn't cover the image. but how do i push the image at the right of the text? 
 it seems i cannot user '\insertBoxR' anymore

Comment: I tested and had no special problem. Could you post what you tried exactly? The only difficulty I've ever seen is that TeX doesn't always calculate the correct number of shorter lines,  but it can be circumvented with the optional argument of \InsertBoxR to specify the number of supplementary shorter lines that are required.

Comment: @Bernard i tried with '\begin{mdframed}[frametitle={my title},style = MyFrame]
\lipsum[1]
\InsertBoxR{3}{
\parbox{5cm}{
\includegraphics[width = 3cm]{images/eso1308b.jpg}}}
 
 
 
 
\lipsum[2]
\end{mdframed}'  i just assumed i had to put insertboxr around parbox,  but i suppose it's not the right way

Comment: Why do you have a \parbox width greater than the width set for \includegraphics?

Comment: @Bernard i made some tests with different dimensions and i forgot to change it back

Comment: In any case, adding \raggedleft before \includegraphics solved the placement problem for different widths, and with the same width for both, there's nothing to be added.

Comment: @Bernard it doesn't behave in the same manner.  i added 2 pictures to show the difference in the first message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132550/discussion-between-bernard-and-alucard).